# Django Model.objects.all() and Model.objects.get(pk=?) return two different results

Tags: django, google-cloud-datastore, django-nonrel

I have a basic model called `Restaurant`

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(Place, primary_key=True)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField()
    serves_hotdog = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s the restaurant' % self.place.name
```

Querying with `Restaurant.objects.all()` and `Restaurant.objects.get()` yields two different results in which only the former is correct.

```
# this is correct
>>> r=Restaurant.objects.all()
>>> r
[<Restaurant: Hogwarts the restaurant>, <Restaurant: Domino the restaurant>]
>>> r[0].serves_hotdog
True

# this is not correct
>>> r0=Restaurant.objects.get(pk=4556376185503744)
>>> r0.serves_hotdog
False

# although they have the same pk
>>> r0.pk == r[0].pk
True
# their property values are different
>>> r[0].serves_hotdog == r0.serves_hotdog
False
>>> r[0].serves_pizza == r0.serves_pizza
False
```

Has anyone seen anything similar to this?

Comment: Are you certain they have the same pk? Have you tried changing `r0 == r[0]` to `r0.pk == r[0].pk`

Comment: Yes. `r0.pk == r[0].pk` returns True.

Comment: Have you modified the objects at any point?

Comment: @Simeon Visser No. I created a new project and copied this model from the documentation. It's very minimal and I still have this error. If it helps, I'm running django 1.4. on gae.

Comment: I can explain the above if you had modified the objects but not if you've never modified the attributes.

Comment: That's pretty obvious, but make sure there is no ORM level caching installed in your project (eg. third party apps like Johny Cache or Cache Machine).

Comment: Under GAE django queries will behave differently as the GAE database is a non relational database. The query methods have been altered by the Django-nonrel project to work in a similar method to SQL django, this could be causing the strange behaviour.

Comment: @HenryFlorence Yes indeed. I found the problem. Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Django-nonrel on GAE, make sure that you don't set `primary_key=True` for related models because the engine will use the same primary key for both models. For example, in my case, I have `Restaurant` and `Place` with `OneToOneRelationship`. If we use `Place` as primary key for `Restaurant`, a restaurant object created from a place object will share the same pk, thus messing up `Restaurant.objects.get(pk=)`.

Dropping the primary key rule fixes my problem:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(Place) # no primary_key=True
```

I can't find this information elsewhere, so I'm posting it here. Hope it helps someone else.